# How can I get the Office 365 new List look and feel when I add its view in a webpart?

Tags: 2013, 2016

When I add a webpart in a page, the look and feel is not the same as I get in the new office 365 list view

Is there an option to get the same exact look and feel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In list/library default view we get new experience but when we add list view web part on page it will give us old view. We cannot change new view in list view web part.